# How to filter Object key value based on key provided separately in array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have below sample array which hold nothing but key of object. And I have one object which hold key value pair, so how we can filter the object key based on value present as key in Array?

```
const arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
const obj = {
  A: 'test1',
  B: 'test2',
  F: 'test3',
  G: 'test4'
}
```

expected o/p

```
{
  A: 'test1',
  B: 'test2',
}
```

Comment: I've added links to the duplicate list which may help. This topic is extremely well covered on SO, so search if you need more help.

Comment: It looks like the duplicates do cover your problems. However, if you still think your problem differentiates from the linked posts, edit your question and make clear to us what is different.